# How does Tensorflow know which derivative function to use in minimize()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

```
model9 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x1,w9)+b)
model10 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(model9,w10)+b)

error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model10-y))
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(error)
```

1. Is tensorflow really so smart, it would 'iterate' through all layers and check activaction function and apply gradient decent based on activation function derivative?
2. What if I think learning rate for model 9 should be 0.01? How do I configue that on network then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is constructing a TensorFlow computation graph consisting of nodes representing the operations and variables. Since TensorFlow knows the gradient for each of the operations (ie the gradient of the operations's output with respect to each of its inputs), it can use the backpropagation algorithm to update the variables during gradient descent, applying the correct derivatives for each activation function along the way. See this excellent explanation of backpropagation: http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/notes3.pdf

Regarding using different learning rates for each layer, this is not so straightforward, but you can achieve something like this by splitting the minimise call into its 2 constituent parts: compute_gradients and apply_gradients and then modify the gradient to effectively change your learning rate. Something like this:

```
model9 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x1,w9)+b)
model10 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(model9,w10)+b)
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model10-y))

optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)    
gradients = optimiser.compute_gradients(error, [w9, w10]) # Compute the gradients of error with respect to w9 and w10

# gradients is a list of tuples [(gradient, variable)]
gradients[0][0] *= 10  # Multiply the gradient of w9 by 10 to increase the learning rate
train = optimiser.apply_gradients(gradients)  # New train op
```

Comment: Note: Adam keeps track of statistics for each variable to dynamically adjust the learning rates, so this technique may not be so effective, except early in training.

Answer (score 1):

> Is tensorflow really so smart, it would 'iterate' through all layers and check activaction function and apply gradient decent based on activation function derivative?

Yes. That's the whole point of using Tensorflow.